# Dynamically adding a textbox to a panel on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I just don't understand how this is done. I've gone through several questions here and from a few other websites.

Basically, a company will be adding process steps, and I want there to be a textbox with a button next to it that reads "Add another step." Once clicked, a new textbox will appear beneath the current one, and the button will be moved next to the new text box. What do I need to do?

Comment: Creating the controls manually seems like a very cumbersome method. Would a grid with an add new row at the bottom not be enough?

Comment: Maybe, I'd just like to learn this way since it does seem like it could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally found an answer I can understand. Using listviews seems to be a good way to go. I found this website

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109000946/http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2008/10/19/asp.net-alternatives-to-dynamic-controls---part-1.aspx)

And I got the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well things will get a little more complex once you ask how to maintain ViewState.  However, since you didn't ask that (yet), the simple answer is just that on button click event you should instantiate a new TextBox and Insert it into the Controls before the Button.

Comment: I've done that, but it only adds one more, then it doesn't do anything but refresh the page it seems